# Float right two span elements in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've been trying to have two span elements, one with Bootstrap 4 class 'close' and the other with class 'badge', floated right. The thing is if I add float-right to the badge, they always end up right next to each other. Or, if I use clear: right, the badge falls to the end of the div.

This needs to be my outline:

[image]

Here's the HTML I have so far:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <img src="image.png">
    <h1 class="card-title d-inline">Title</h1>
    <span class="badge badge-default d-inline">Badge</span>
    <h2 class="card-subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that with Bootstrap 4? Thank you!

Comment: It's all inside a card. So it's <div class="card"><div class="card-header> -
 my code - </div></div>

Comment: Sorry sorry, I've added it in now.

Comment: Ok, so the answer I posted should work

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't. The badge sticks to the close span again.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Please, check the image I posted with my question. The badge needs to be below the close span and in the same row/line as the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use margin or padding (spacing utils) around the badge..

http://www.codeply.com/go/XEbOw2F29d

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <span class="close">x</span>
        <span class="badge badge-default float-right m-2">Badge</span>
        <img src="//placehold.it/40">
        <h1 class="card-title d-inline">Title</h1>
        <h2 class="card-subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

***EDIT***

If you're looking for something like shown in your image, it's not a simple matter of `float-right`. You'll need to use the spacing utils to adjust the elements..

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header pt-0">
        <div class="w-100 text-right close">x</div>
        <img src="//placehold.it/60" class="float-left mt-2 mr-2">
        <span class="badge badge-default float-right mt-2">Badge</span>
        <h1 class="card-title my-0"> Title</h1>
        <h2 class="card-subtitle d-inline-block">Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

http://www.codeply.com/go/XEbOw2F29d

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try creating a new `div` and putting inside "Close" and "Badge"? Then you only need to float the div to the right.
Tell me if it works!

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for pointing out the cleaner & simpler solution!